# Retrieve one specific key from JSON array with helpers

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, handlebars.js

I have the following array with an object:

```
"customfield_10297": [
                    {
                        "self": "https://xxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10326",
                        "value": "Manual",
                        "id": "10326"
                    }
                ],
```

And I want to retrieve only the `value` key from it. Is there any way to do it with handlebars? I know only that I can iterate, but the whole array appears in report this way:

```
<br><b>Test Type:</b> {{#each data.jira.customfield_10297}}
                            {{#each this}}
                                <{{@key}}>{{this}}</{{@key}}>
                            {{/each}}
                            {{/each}}
```

Comment: I'm confused ... your "code" never uses the word `value`

Comment: Remove the `{{#each this}}` and just use `{{value}}`.